# Animating row in table view with duration IN Iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios4

Can any body help me that how to animate row in table view.

Like i have 10 rows in table view and i want to add one more row, and I want to animate that row with duration I want it to be. I have used following code,

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

with this code my row is adding and animating, but I need to animate slowly with animation duration,

According to time duration its mush be animated.

Answer (score 0):

I don think you can control the duration of animation for standard animation. You can go for custom animation though where you have control over everything.

Answer (score 0):

@Jay you can put your code in an animation block and there u can specify your required duration for animating the insert and delete of cells in tableview.

You can use blocks or begin animation API to perform animation

Check the documentation of UIView from apple
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: and have you tried that ever with table view animations? you should either edit your answer or provide in example (if you think it will work).